# Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file

Tags: release, apt-get

I am on Desktop with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Intel i3, 4 GB RAM & 320 GB HDD.

Each time I try to install at,  the time based scheduler, using:

```
sudo apt-get install at
```

I get error message,

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  
Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' 
in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I have updated the PPA Universe, but still end up getting this Error.